# Hadoop installation Issue:

Tags: hadoop, installation, hadoop2

I followed [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) tutorial for installation of Hadoop. Unfortunately, when I run the *start-all.sh* script - The following error was printed on console:

```
hduser@dennis-HP:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
hadoop config script is run...
hdfs script is run...
Config parameter : 
16/04/10 23:45:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dennis-HP.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dennis-HP.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dennis-HP.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dennis-HP.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dennis-HP.out
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dennis-HP.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
16/04/10 23:45:55 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
yarn script is run...
starting yarn daemons
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-dennis-HP.out
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-dennis-HP.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-dennis-HP.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 124: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-dennis-HP.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 129: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh: line 130: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-dennis-HP.out: No such file or directory
```

And when I executed the JPS command, the following error was thrown

```
hduser@dennis-HP:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
3802 Jps
```

I am new to hadoop so please point me to an article that will help me to install hadoop without issues

Or if possible (and more preferable) to resolve the issue faced, please let me know what went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Your current user has limited permissions to /usr/local/hadoop.
Try changing permissions.

> **sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/hadoop/**

Answer (score 2):

Please check permission are properly set on the folder using commands chmod or chown.

Hadoop provides individual nodes to start and stop services viz., 
Hadoop-daemon.sh start [Node]

Similarly there are scripts to start/stop yarn.
Below post has step by stem details Install Apache Hadoop
http://www.hadoopstrata.com/staticpost?postNbr=7

Answer (score 1):

Quite honestly I do not know why I got that error.. but I removed my entire installation using the instructions provided in [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463243/how-to-uninstall-or-remove-hadoop-from-ubuntu) and re-installed it by using the installation method described in the official site - [HERE](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html)

But you were right @Krishna, the logs were created automatically after installation. My guess is that the installation that I used earlier had configuration details that were outdated and in all likeliness messed with the installation of Hadoop

Answer (score 0):

Check `/usr/local/hadoop/logs` permissions . If it is not under hduser change the ownership.

`sudo chown -R username:group directory`

Comment: Actually there is no logs directory under "/usr/local/hadoop" did I miss a configuration somewhere?

Comment: if you check inside hadoop-env.sh file, you will find `# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER`. If the logs directory is not there means it will create automatically

Comment: The logs files have not been created though.. I followed the tutorial in http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php. Has that messed the installation?

Answer (score 0):

Well I faced similar issue , I found that my HADOOP_PREFIX path in hadoop-env.sh was incomplete.
Instead of pointing to my installation directory it was pointing to directory which was owned by root.
Fixed that and everything worked!!

Correct path

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/karan/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.2.1
```

Wrong Path

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/hadoop-install/hadoop-3.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem

i deleted this folder :

hadoop-hadoop_amine-datanode-amine.out located in : usr/local/hadoopy/logs

start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh

jps:

14048 Jps
32226 ResourceManager
32403 NodeManager
6164 SecondaryNameNode
13548 DataNode
5806 NameNode

Answer (score -1):

have you tried `start-dfs.sh`
try the following commands and see whats the response

```
hdfs namenode -format
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```